# 0xc000000d Error (Windows 10). After manually replacing an AppleMTN.sys driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, drivers, bsod

I'm on Windows 10 and I wanted to read a MacOS external drive so I searched and found that bootcamp drivers issue. Downloaded them, and placed the AppleMNT.sys and AppleHFS.sys into C:\Windows\System32\drivers, replacing an older pair of drivers that were there. After restarting the computer, BSOD and whatever key I press (debugging, safe mode, etc) I'm sent back to the main BSOD screen, which claims:

Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
The operating system couldn't be loaded because a critical system driver is missing or contains errors.
File: \WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\AppleMNT.sys
Error code: 0xc000000d

I've searched this issue and tried everything, searched every error code, tried every solution, etc and can't solve the problem. I've created a bootable Win10 usb and used the repair this computer>troubleshoot>advanced options path.The list of things I've tried:

1) 
Of course, I want to delete those drivers so I tried to boot in safe mode. I followed the screen instructions and press the F4 when in BSOD, but as I said, it gets me back to the BSOD screen. Also I tried to force an F8 safe mode by typing  bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy in command propmt. I get the F8 option but as I press safe mode, it gets me the same error: appleMNT.sys etc.

2) 
System Restore to a previous point -> error:

System Restore could not acces a file. This is probable because an anti-virus program is running on the computer. Temporarily disable your antivirus program and retry System Restore.
An unspecified error ocurred during System Restore (0x80070005)

How can I disable the anti-virus if I can't boot even in safe mode?

3) 
Startup Repair -> error

Startup Repair couldn’t repair your PC
Log file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt

As I check that log file within the command propmt, I get this:

(lots of 'completed successfully, error code = 0x0')

Root cause found: Unspecified changes to system configuration might have cause the problem.
Repair action: [blank], Result: Failed. Error code = 0x32
Repair action: System Restore, Result: Failed. Error code = 0x1f
Repair action: System files integrity check and repair, Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490

Session details...

(lots of 'completed successfully, error code = 0x0')

Root cause found: Boot critical file c:\windows\system32\drivers\applemnt.sys is corrupt
Repair action: File repair, Result: Failed. Error code = 0x2
Repair action: System files integrity check and repair, Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490

4) 
Command prompt lines (I note that it shows X:\Sources as a default because it’s a temporary containter. I’ve tried the following command both in X:\ as well as changing to C:)

4A) 
Running Windows System File Checker
sfc /scannow
Begginig system scan… Verification 100% complete. Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

4B) 
I think this might be a solution: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-error-code-0xc0000359/dfe6024f-dce4-4031-93d6-48815fe9e60b
Should I follow that replacing UsbFilter_Install.inf with my AppleMNT.sys ? Or maybe Renaming it instead of Deleting it is enought to bypass the error.

If not, is there a way to bypass that BSOD and enter the safe mode? Can I force it with the command prompt? Or can I disable or delete those two drivers from there?

THANK YOU and excuse the long post

Comment: Boot from an OS on CD and delete the two files.